# Using TPM attestation on a Rapberry Pi 3 Device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

I have followed the [Quickstart to Provision a simulated TPM device using the Azure IoT C SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device). I now want to do the same on a Raspberry Pi 3 - with an add-on GPIO TPM module for the Raspberry Pi platform based on an Infineon Optiga™ SLB 9670 TPM 2.0. Will the same tutorial work on a real TPM device? This is, the step [Read cryptographic keys from the TPM device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device#read-cryptographic-keys-from-the-tpm-device) will work seamlessly and I will be able to retrieve **Registration ID** and **Endorsement Key** after running **./tpm_device_provision** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found on the documentation [Use a Infineon OPTIGA™ TPM SLx 9670 on a Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Linux OS to test Azure Device Provisioning Service for Azure IoT Edge](https://catalog.azureiotsolutions.com/details?title=OPTIGA-TPM-SLB-9670-Iridium-Board&source=all-devices-page) that **./tpm_device_provision** will retrieve **Registration ID** and **Endorsement Key** on the TPM module!

Comment: Yes it will work, and remember to add the device overlay etc.